# CentOS Virutal Machine is unable to PING the Gateway

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ping

I've installed a CentOS Virutal Machine on the following hypervisor - **VMWare Workstation 8**
All of a sudden this morning , I'm unable to PING my gateway. I can PING the same gateway from the host machine however.

Here are some outputs I've captured to help analyze the root cause of this issue.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:40:33:C9  
          inet addr:172.16.192.133  Bcast:172.16.195.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:33c9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1083 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:147336 (143.8 KiB)  TX bytes:239650 (234.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:612224 (597.8 KiB)  TX bytes:612224 (597.8 KiB)
```

It was working fine last night. Here are some additional outputs of relevant commands 
172.16.192.1 is the IP Address of the default gateway

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 172.16.192.1
PING 172.16.192.1 (172.16.192.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.192.133 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.192.133 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

root@localhost ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.192.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.16.192.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Client IP Static?
Did you change the VMs Network Adapter by accident?

As far as I understand, your host can reach the gateway, your client doesn't, but your client still has a ip address